# Редирект с помощью REQUEST_URI в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Доброго времени суток.

Требуется на сайте сделать редирект с http://sitename.ru/okna/ на http://sitename.ru/okna.html. При этом подстраницы, например http://sitename.ru/okna/zakolochennye.html, редиректить не должны.

Пробую в htaccess следующее выражение:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/okna/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /okna.html? [R=301,L]
```

И ничего не происходит. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так и как надо?

```
##
# @version      $Id: htaccess.txt 21101 2011-04-07 15:47:33Z dextercowley $
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2011 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##


## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

Redirect 301 /component/content/category/80-natyazhnye-potolki.html /natyazhnye-potolki.html
Redirect 301 /component/content/article/80-natyazhnye-potolki/69-natyazhnye-potolki.html /natyazhnye-potolki.html
Redirect 301 /component/content/article/90-stati/100-regulirovka-okon.html /articles/okna/remont-plastikovyh-okon.html
Redirect 301 /metalloplastikovye-okna/90-stati/107-proizvodstvoplastikovieoknadveriifasadnyyesistemyvgatchine.html /metalloplastikovye-okna.html
Redirect 301 /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/geona/category/82-tsvetovaya-gamma.html /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/geona/tsvetovaya-gamma.html
Redirect 301 /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/verda/category/62-двери-экошпон.html /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/verda/ecoshpon.html
Redirect 301 /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/verda/category/64-двери-раздвижные.html /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/verda/razdvizhnye.html
Redirect 301 /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/zodchij/category/74-tsvetovaya-gamma.html /mezhkomnatnye-dveri/zodchij/tsvetovaya-gamma.html
Redirect 301 /zabory/76-zabory.html /zabory/zabory.html
Redirect 301 /natyazhnye-potolki/106-natyazhnyepotolkivgatchineigatchinskomrayone.html /articles/potolki/podvesnye-ili-natyazhnye-potolki.html
Redirect 301 /natyazhnye-potolki/69-natyazhnye-potolki.html /natyazhnye-potolki.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} otdelka-okon.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} showall=&start=1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /osteklenie-balkonov/otdelka.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/metalloplastikovye-okna/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /metalloplastikovye-okna.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=90:stati&id=93:kak-vibrat-potolok&Itemid=476&option=com_content&view=article [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /articles/potolki/kak-vybrat-natyazhnoy-potolok-v-komnatu.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=81:veka&catid [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /metalloplastikovye-okna.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=97:pamyatka&catid=90:stati&Itemid=465 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /articles/potolki/pamyatka-pokupatelyu-natyazhnyh-potolkov.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=97:pamyatka&catid=90:stati&Itemid=486 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /articles/potolki/pamyatka-pokupatelyu-natyazhnyh-potolkov.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=100:regulirovka-okon&catid=90:stati&Itemid=468 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /articles/okna/remont-plastikovyh-okon.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=100:regulirovka-okon&catid=90:stati&Itemid=486 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /articles/okna/remont-plastikovyh-okon.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=80&Itemid=471 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /natyazhnye-potolki.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=85&Itemid=476 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /reshetki.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=86&Itemid=477 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zabory.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=87&Itemid=478 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /kozyrki.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Так может сервер не apache, а nginx у вас? И `RewriteEngine On` есть в начале? И включена ли обработка файлов .htaccess у вас в apache?

Comment: Я в данном вопросе некомпетентен. Но RewriteEngine On есть, и другие другие правила, мною писанные, сервер обрабатывает корректно. Однако в других правилах я редиректил с урлов с GET-параметрами, поэтому использовал RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}.

Comment: Если у вас там много правил, то вполне может быть, что есть конфликт между ними. Так что для ответа на ваш вопрос, думаю, нужно видеть весь файл .htaccess.

Comment: Добавил содержимое файла. Несрабатывающая инструкция - 11-й абзац снизу.

Comment: Я бы поставил это правило сразу за `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: Или после строки `## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.` если сначала хотите блокировать супер хакеров.

Comment: О, Великий! Заработало, спасибо. :)